# Assign a device to an object to perform input action in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game where two players compete against each other. 
I set up the input system to control my Object, but every controller now controls every object.
I am thinking of somehthing like...

```
action.performed += context => if(?Device.ID? == this.deviceID) action()
```

Comment: Does [this answer](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1096806/view.html) help?

Comment: Sadly not, this answer is about an older version of unity's input system.

Comment: In the old input system as much as the new, you normally would do something like player1 directions, player2 directions as you define the keys inputs each player would use

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it,
`context.control.device`

Comment: what namespace does `context` come from?